# Tie::File::AsHash troubleshooting

Tags: perl, perl-module, text-parsing, tie

I'm trying to use Perls's Tie::File::AsHash to load a big file into a hash. However, it seems to get keys but not the values. The code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Tie::File::AsHash;

tie my %what, 'Tie::File::AsHash', './test_tiehash', split => "\t" or die "Problem tying hash: $!";
foreach my $test(keys %what){
    print "$test $what{$test}\n";
}
untie %what
```

The file I'm testing it on contains one only line, with a tab after the last number:

ENSMUSG00000020333|ENSMUST00000000145|54361198|54361535 AGAACGTTGCGGGGCGGGCGGCCCAGCCCCTCCCCCAGTCGGGCTCGGCAGTTCGGATGCCGCTAGATTGCTCTCTCACTTCTGGAGAAGATGCAGACCCAGGAGATCCTGAGGATCCTGCGGCTGCCCGAGCTATCGGACTTGGGCCAGTTTTTCCGCAGCCTCTCAGCTACCACCCTCGACGGTGGTGGAGCCCGGCGATCTGTGATTGGGGGTTGCACT

When i run it, I get:
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test_hashes.pl line 8,  line 2.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, good people. The problem was that the supposed hash keys were longer than allowed.

Comment: No, no it wasn't. You have simply truncated the keys far enough to exclude all the pipe `|` characters! See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in [`Tie::Array::AsHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aAsHash) (on which [`Tie::File::AsHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile%3a%3aAsHash) depends) whereby the *key* part of each line in the file is used as-is in a  regular expression to extract the corresponding *value*. That means the value isn't found if any regex metacharacters appear in the key.

You can fix this temporarily for yourself by changing line 59 of `Tie/Array/AsHash.pm` from

```
my $fetchrx = qr/^$key$self->{split}(.*)/s;
```

to

```
my $split = $self->{split};
my $fetchrx = $split->isa('Regexp') ?
    qr/^\Q$key\E$split(.*)/s :
    qr/^\Q$key$split\E(.*)/s;
```

Alternatively, unless you need the facility whereby a change in the hash is reflected by modifying the contents of the file, you could just write some code like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %what = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'test_tiehash.txt';
  map { chomp; split /\t/; } <$fh>;
};

for my $test(keys %what){
  print "$test $what{$test}\n";
}
```

Meanwhile I shall mention this to the author of the module in the hope of getting it fixed in the near future.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. But there is no such line in Tie/File/AsHash.pm. Do you know how to do something similar there? Thanks again!

Comment: I can't really help without seeing what you've done. Has the change made any difference at all? You've changed line 59 of `Tie/Array/AsHash.pm` right? It's possible you have multiple versions of the module. Try printing `$INC{'Tie/Array/AsHash.pm'}` in your program to show the path to the version you should be patching.

Comment: Note that I've moved the `\E` in my solution to make it a more general fix that accounts for regex metacharacters in the `split` value as well as in the key.

Comment: @Miller: Thanks for pointing that out - it clearly needs to distinguish between a text split and a regex so I've rewritten it